# I have a glitch in my program which keeps opening a specific form over and over again after the form is hidden

Tags: c#, winforms

I am an AS Software Development student and I have made an Electronics Quiz for my CA. I have come across a glitch which I cannot seem to fix. It has started to bug me and I can't think of what is wrong. My teacher also cannot see what is wrong. Everything else is working. Here is the code:

```
namespace MyQuiz2
 {
     public partial class DragDropYear8_Question1 : Form
     {
         public DragDropYear8_Question1(string name, int quizSelection)
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             CenterToScreen();
             setupQuestion();
         }

         private void setupQuestion()
         {
             AllowDropping();

             ScoreLbl.Text = "Score: " + StartScreen.Player.Score;

             LEDImg.Visible = true;
             ResistorImg.Visible = true;
             VairiableResistorImg.Visible = true;

             timer1.Interval = 1000;
             timer1.Start();

             if (_time1 == 0)
             {
                 ShowNextQuestion();
             }
         }

         //variable decleration

         private int _time1 = 15;
         private int _correctAnswers = 0;

         //Set up timer

         private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             _time1--;
             TimerLbl.Text = "Time: " + _time1;
         }

         //Question setup
         private void ShowNextQuestion()
         {
             _time1 = 0;
             Hide();
             new DragDropYear8_Question2(StartScreen.Player.Username, 10).Show();
         }

         private void AllowDropping()//allows the label to be dropped onto a picture box.
        {
            VairiableResistorImg.AllowDrop = true;
            ResistorImg.AllowDrop = true;
            LEDImg.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        //Tells the program that a label has been grabbed
        private void LabelGrabbed(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Label selectedLabel = (Label)sender;
            selectedLabel.DoDragDrop(selectedLabel.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        //allows the label to be droped onto the PictureBox
        private void AllowDragDropCopy(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        private void UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenCorrect()//updates all labels on the current form if the answers are correct
        {
            _correctAnswers++;
            StartScreen.Player.IncreaseScore();
            ScoreLbl.Text = "Score: " + StartScreen.Player.Score;

            if (_correctAnswers == 3)
            {
                ShowNextQuestion();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong()//updates all labels on the current form if the answers are incorrect
        {
            _correctAnswers++;
            ScoreLbl.Text = "Score: " + StartScreen.Player.Score;

            if (_correctAnswers == 3)
            {
                ShowNextQuestion();
            }
        }

        //checks if the right label has been dropped onto the correct picture box

        private void VairiableResistorDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            /*if the correct label is droped then the score and labels 
            will be updated and that label and picture box will hide*/
            if (result == "Vairiable Resistor")//checks for right answer
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenCorrect();
                VairiableResistorImg.Visible = false;
                VairiableResistorLbl.Visible = false;
            }
            //if the anser is wrong then it will hide the picture box and the dragged label
            else if (result == "Resistor")
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong();
                ResistorLbl.Visible = false;
                VairiableResistorImg.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (result == "Light Emmiting Diode")
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong();
                LEDLbl.Visible = false;
                VairiableResistorImg.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void LEDDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            /*if the correct label is droped then the score and labels 
            will be updated and that label and picture box will hide*/
            if (result == "Light Emmiting Diode")//checks for right answer
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenCorrect();
                LEDImg.Visible = false;
                LEDLbl.Visible = false;
            }
            //if the anser is wrong then it will hide the picture box and the dragged label
            else if (result == "Resistor")
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong();
                ResistorLbl.Visible = false;
                LEDImg.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (result == "Vairiable Resistor")
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong();
                LEDImg.Visible = false;
                VairiableResistorLbl.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void ResistorDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            /*if the correct label is droped then the score and labels 
            will be updated and that label and picture box will hide*/
            if (result == "Resistor")//checks for right answer
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenCorrect();
                ResistorImg.Visible = false;
                ResistorLbl.Visible = false;
            }
            //if the anser is wrong then it will hide the picture box and the dragged label
            else if (result == "Light Emmiting Diode")
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong();
                ResistorImg.Visible = false;
                LEDLbl.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (result == "Vairiable Resistor")
            {
                UpdateScoreAndLabelWhenWrong();
                ResistorImg.Visible = false;
                VairiableResistorLbl.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }`
```

The problem is that when I change from the first dragdrop question to the second dragdrop question. Randomly during the second form, the first dragdrop question form will open. It does this the hole way through the quiz. Latter on in the quiz the game loadscreen also does this. The code is as follows:

```
namespace MyQuiz2
{
    public partial class GameLoading : Form
    {
        public GameLoading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CenterToScreen();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        //Timer and Progressbar setup
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //randome number generator for ProgressBar increments
            Random random = new Random();
            int Increment = random.Next(10, 20);
            Random random2 = new Random();
            int _Increment = random2.Next(1, 5);

            timer1.Interval = 1000;

            if (progressBar1.Value <= 80)
            {
                progressBar1.Increment(Increment);
                /*picks a random number between 5 and 10 to increment the ProgressBar by if
                 the value of the Progress bar is less than or equal to 80*/
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Increment(_Increment);
                // picks a randome number between 1 and 5 to incremnt by when the ProgressBar is more then 80
            }

            LoadingLbl.Text = "Loading Game..." + progressBar1.Value + "%";

            //When progress bar is at its maximum value the next form will show
            if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                LoadingLbl.Text = "Loading Game... 100%";
                CheckScore();
            }
        }

        private void CheckScore()
        {
            if (StartScreen.Player.Score >= 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you got more than 80% of the quiz correct. You can proceed to the Game", "Well done!!");
                timer1.Stop();
                new GameMenu().Show();
                Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You got under 80% in the quiz but you can't play the game. Try again.", "Unlucky, Try again");
                timer1.Stop();
                new EndScreen(false).Show();
                Hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 
 I will [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i73uug5hm1ofmf2/AABcpE9YaEMxidHbsi6Iifg6a?dl=0) if you would like to have a look for yourself(the source code and a video is included). Thanks
[This screen shot shows the problem at the drag drop questions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixewp.png) [As you an see from this image, it keeps on multiplying. The same thing happens with the game loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lqxB.png)

I think the problem is that the timer does not stop which will keep on opening the forms but I'm not sure. I hope this lets you understand my problem better. Thanks

Comment: Why link a **video** of the problem and source code when you can just tell us what the problem is and post the code here? I'm not going to watch a video of your code/problem... And I'm certainly not downloading anything out of your dropbox to do it!

Comment: What @Ron Beyer said. This site isn't for sharing videos. We look at/investigate code issues.

Comment: Why a video?  I think I speak for everyone when I say I prefer a cell phone picture of a compressed jpg screenshot of a court room artist sketch of your original code.  Its really the only format that illustrates your code problem

Comment: Don't link a video. Nobody will watch it. Take time to explain what's wrong and present a repeatable piece of code with your question. Who knows, but making sure you ask a good question, you might even find the solution yourself.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I updated it to make it more specific.

Comment: This is definitely a lot better. One more item, though: can you also include a more informative title? The title should concisely describe what you're asking about so that other people can tell whether the question is relevant to them more easily.

Comment: ok. ill change it now

Comment: @EJoshuaS is this any better?

Comment: You may be right with the Timer. Have you tried placing a timer1.Stop() right before the Hide() in ShowNextQuestion() to see if this fixes it?  Also, calling the next question from the previous form may not be the best idea. You may want to have all the questions called from the main form (or the one that calls DragDropYear8_Question1).

Comment: I have put in a timer1.Stop() where you said @TroyMac1ure and that didn't work. I am struggling to understand your suggestion and I want to make sure I understand. Are you saying I should open all of the forms for that question in the when the Year8 button is pressed on the start screen and then Hide() the questions on each form instead of opening and hiding each form from the NextQuestion() method.

Answer (score 0):

You an still call each question as a form. I would have a function that shows the requested question. This can be called by a second function that can keep track of the question you are on. Also, I would probably call and destroy each form, so that you don't have unnecessary forms hanging around. Something like this (writing this on my phone so take it as an outline more than direct code) :

```
public void CallQuestions()
{
   int QuestionNumber = 1;
   do {
      if Question(QuestionNumber) 
         QuestionNumber++;
   } while (Exit == false) ;
}

public boolean Question(int number) 
{
   Form QuestionForm = null;
   switch (number) 
   {
      case 1:
         QuestionForm = new DragDropYear8_Question1;
         break;
      //... 
   } 
   if (QuestionForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
      return true;
   return false;
```

}